Is it possible to set an embedded video to play again at the end?
        if (item.getAttribute("value").includes('http')) {
        
            document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = `<iframe width="1179" height="663" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/668nUCeBHyY?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&autopause=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>errerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>`   
                console.log("I'm here  if")   
                const video = document.getElementById('player');           
        } 

hi everyone I wanna ask u if it's possible to set the embedded video to replay at the end. if it's possible how can I do that

Tnx bro it's working

You need to add loop=1 and the playlist parameter.
This is how your code should look:


if (item.getAttribute("value").includes('http')) {
    document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = `
        <iframe width="1179" height="663" 
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/668nUCeBHyY?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&playlist=668nUCeBHyY" 
                frameborder="0" 
                allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
                referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" 
                allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
    console.log("I'm here if");
                const video = document.getElementById('player');           

}



